# scraping a website - is this even possible?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I'd like to extract the Rates values for properties in Northern Ireland from the LPS website http://lpsni.gov.uk/vListDCV/search.asp?submit=form

I'm a reasonable php programmer but I haven't a clue how I'd go about doing this. Can someone point me in the direction of what I need to find out in order to do this?

Is it even possible to do what I want?

Comment: Scrapy is my favorite tool for this - http://scrapy.org/

Comment: Automation of access is a violation of standard `.gov.uk` website EULA. There are also many questions on here dealing with similar things, and thousands of articles online about it too. A quick Google for "php web spider" or "php download url" would have given you everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is very do-able.
Pointers:**  Ignore trying to go in through the form, all the data can be reached via static links from http://lpsni.gov.uk/vListDCV/districts.asp as all the propertys are fixed it becomes merely a case of scraping each layer for links to build loops within loops eg: councils-wards-streets-etc  till you eventually get down to the meat and pull it out using cURL or even just file_get_contents and regex off the bits you don't want. Store for later use in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping data using Php is lengthy and code-driven. You write the script and extract the data from the site but I suggest to automate the process.